# URL Rewrite - Remove String

Tags: apache, .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to rewrite URLs that are processed by my CMS. Essentially, when it sees:

www.mydomain.com/du/section/title

It needs to rewrite the URL and process:

www.mydomain.com/section/title

I tried the pattern `(.*)(/du/)(.*)` and then having the rewrite URL be just {R:1}/{R:3} where {R:1} is everything before /du/ and {R:3} is everything after it but I haven't had any luck.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, doesn't have to be written for IIS, can be an Apache mod_rewrite and I can import it.

Here is my rewrite rule in my web.config file:

```
`<rule name="DU Rewrite" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
     <match url="([^/]*/)(du/)(.*)" />
     <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
     <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}{R:3}" appendQueryString="true" />
 </rule>`
```

Thanks

Comment: The regex you want is `([^/]*/)(du/)(.*)`

Comment: That still leaves the /du/ in the URL and doesn't process the correct one. It does test correctly and groups the necessary pieces of the URL into the right groups but does not rewrite it.

Comment: Then your problem is in your configuration, which you haven't posted.